# Calling different functions inside a class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm having a question related to functions in a class. My goal is to write a program with a `Visualization` class, which handles all the GUI related stuff with tkinter and another class called `SensorHandling`, which will mainly test sensors whether they work or not and return the result, which will then be displayed in `Visualization`. I'm having problems with my GUI class.

I have two different functions inside the class Visualization, namely StartPage and `TestingHead_Page`. I pass root in order for them to be able to modify my application directly. Now, I want to display the `TestingHead_Page` with my button `bTestingHead`, but I get an error that `TestingHead_Page` is not defined.

How do I go about this problem?
Criticism is always appreciated as I want to learn.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import serial
import platform
import time

LARGEFONT = ("Verdana", 35)

class Visualization:

    def StartPage(self, root):

        lTitle= ttk.Label(root, text ="Title", font = LARGEFONT)
        lTitle.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "N", padx = 10, pady = 10)
        lTitle.config(font = ('Calibri', 32, 'bold'))

        lTesting = ttk.Label(root, text = "Testing", font = ('calibri', 20))
        lTesting.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        bTestingHead = ttk.Button(root, text = "Testing Head", command = self.TestingHead_Page(root))
        bTestingHead.grid(row = 2 , column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 20)

        exit = tk.PhotoImage(file = "exit_icon.png")
        bExit = ttk.Button(root, text = "exit", image = exit, command = root.destroy)
        bExit.image = exit
        bExit.place(relx = 1.0, rely = 0.0, anchor = 'ne')

    def TestingHead_Page(self, root):

        lTitle = ttk.Label(root, text = "Testing Head")
        lTitle.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "W", padx = 10, pady = 10)

        bStartPage = ttk.Button(root, text = "Start Page", command = "")
        bStartPage.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "E", padx = 10, pady = 10)

        exit = tk.PhotoImage(file = "exit_icon.png")
        bExit = ttk.Button(root, text = "exit", image = exit, command = root.destroy)
        bExit.image = exit
        bExit.place(relx = 1.0, rely = 0.0, anchor = 'ne')

    if __name__ == "__main__":

        root = tk.Tk()
        guiref = StartPage(self, root)
        tk.mainloop()

#class SensorHandling():
```

Comment: Looks like you tried to take a popular way of displaying multiple pages in tkinter (accepted answer to [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)) which involves making each "page" a separate **class**, and nested them inside your `Visualization`. While that's probably doable, you've done it wrong by converting each page class into a **method** of that class. Besides that, nesting classes is seldom done in Python because there's little to gain by doing so and they're somewhat of a pain to work with.

Comment: I chose this approach because it seemed easier to work with if I have only one class with all GUI related stuff and one class doing the work for me. Isn't it less of a pain if I do it this way or as you said by making each page a separate class?

Comment: I would suggest making each page class a separate class (as they are in the example I mentioned) but put them all into separate module which gets `import`ed into the script that defines your `Visualization` class — which can then use them as necessary. You could also put them and the  `Visualization` class together in one script and then have your main code import that module to do that part of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. But I didn't get one part of your answer. You suggest making each page a separate class but still put them into separate modules?

Comment: I meant make each page a separate `class` and put them all (together) in a separate module in `import` that one thing.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, you need to pass the current instance, referenced through the `self` keyword, explicitly in the class's methods:

```
def StartPage(self, root):
    ...

def TestingHead_Page(self, root):
    ...
```

While inside the class, you would call them like this:

```
self.StartPage(root)
self.TestingHead_Page(root)
```

Read up on [classes in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Also, from the code, it seems like `TestingHead_Page` should return some value since you try to capture that in `command = TestingHead_Page(root)`, so you need to fix that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did think about this too, however, when I pass self as an argument I get a NameError "name 'self' is not defined", what am I missing?

Comment: Edit the code with self added and let us know which line gives the error. @Dimilo Outside the class, you would call these methods like `guiref.StartPage(root)`, etc. btw.

Comment: Alright, I did edit the code and line 64 gives the error wher I call StartPage for the first time: 'guiref = StartPage(self, root)'

Comment: You don't pass `self` outside the class. You don't do anything with the keyword `self` outside the class, it has no meaning. When you call like `guiref.StartPage(root)`, `self` is passed implicitly. Read up on the `self` keyword in Python. @Dimilo

Comment: I understand that you don't use `self` outside a class, but it is in the class `Visualization` together with the if statement, isn't it?

Comment: I missed that, you need to move that if statement outside the class. It won't work otherwise. It's not part of your class or any method. @Dimilo

Comment: Alright, got it to work now. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. I got a different problem now but I'll try to debug that myself anyway. I have one last question, is there no way to create root and run the mainloop inside a class?

Comment: You can do it in `__init__` (constructor) of your class. Also, please mark the answer as accepted it the issue is resolved. @Dimilo

Comment: If you do it in the `Visualization` class' `__init__()` method and make it an instance attribute: i.e. `self.root = tk.Tk()` then you won't need to explicitly pass it as an argument to each method when you call them — they can each just refer to it via `self.root`.